# Beginning program to print a gridview1 on the asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have a database "Pubs" with a table "authors".  I have made a dbml file from the database by dragging over "authors".

Here is the "Default.aspx.vb"

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim db As New PubsContext
        Dim products = From p In db.authors _
                       Select p

        GridView1.DataSource = author
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the class for it: "Class1.vb"

```
Partial Public Class PubsContext
    Public Function GetProductsByCategory(ByVal id1 As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of authors)
        Return From p In Me.authors _
               Where p.ProductID = id1 _
               Select p
    End Function
End Class
```

There is a red underline for corrections in authors and author.  What should I do?

Comment: What is the error in the error list tool window?

Comment: There were a list of stubs and generating method, property and fields but when I tried each one and I keep getting "Object not queryable. Make sure you are not missing an assembly reference and/or namespace import for LINQ."

Comment: Is your code in the same project as the "db" type? If not, then you have to add a reference to "System.Data.Linq"

Comment: All in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. In the solutions explorer.

Comment: Already have a link "System.Data.Linq

Comment: Your Page_Load code does not seem to make sense - you are creating a var called products but then binding the Gridview to one called author - where is this defined?

Comment: in Default.aspx. "Products" should be "authors" as corrected in my code.

Comment: @user1228044 can you show that code as well then?

Comment: Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim author As Object
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim db As New PubsContext
        Dim authors = From p In dbo.authors _
                       Select p

        GridView1.DataSource = author
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub

Comment: @user1228044 can you update your question (you can click edit underneath the question) as it is a little bit confusing as it is at the moment